# While/For/If Else Loop after checking user input

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I'm new to Python and learning. I'm trying to write a program to:

1. User input full name (with space)
2. Check duplication to a list (I used split and join to compare strings)
3. If find a duplication, re-input new name
4. If not, simply break the loop and print "Thanks"
5. I only need to print "Duplicated" or "Thanks" 1 time, not multiple times with For loop.

My issue is when I cant re-call the input with my code (with duplicated input) or break the loop (after new name)

```js
list=["M T", "Smith Jenkins", "P T", "C P"]

    while True:
        user=input("Your full name :")
        usercheck="".join(user.split())
        print(usercheck)

        for i in list:
            j="".join(i.split())
            if usercheck ==j:
                print("Duplicated ! Please enter new name")   
                
            else:
                print("Thanks")
            break
```

Comment: Move `break` under `else`.

Comment: `list` is a python built-in function. It is not appropriate to name variable **list**. You could name that variable `list_names = ["M T", "Smith Jenkins", "P T", "C P"]` or `names_list = ["M T", "Smith Jenkins", "P T", "C P"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about that

- if the current name in the iteratation is same :that's a dup
- if the current name is different : you can't conclude there is not dup now, you need to test the others

---

So you can use the `for/else` construction, the `else` will be executed if no `break` has been seen in the loop, in your case if no duplicated has been found, there you'll be able to break the while loop

```
names = []
while True:
    user = input("Your full name :")
    usercheck = "".join(user.split())
    print(usercheck)
    for name in names:
        j = "".join(name.split())
        if usercheck == j:
            print("Duplicated ! Please enter new name")
            break
    else:
        print("Thanks")
        break
```

---

If that is too tricky, you can keep with a variable that will help you know whether you've seen a duplicate or not

```
while True:
    user = input("Your full name :")
    usercheck = "".join(user.split())
    duplicated = False
    for name in names:
        j = "".join(name.split())
        if usercheck == j:
            print("Duplicated ! Please enter new name")
            duplicated = True
            break
    if duplicated:
        print("Thanks")
        break
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I didn't know For/Else exist, your code is exactly what I plan to do, but with For/Else , not If/Else :)

Comment: @Pmt0916 you can now think about accepting the answer (tick on left) and vote it up ;)

Comment: Accepted the answer , but unable to vote due to new account. But thank you :)

Comment: I'm running into new issue with on your code above. For example name : Tom Cruise , if I input randomly a letter Capital (TOm CruISe) , it wont detect and break the the loop as printed "Thanks". I have no clue at the moment now.

Comment: @Pmt0916 as you did for the spaces, do `"".join(user.split()).lower()` and `"".join(name.split()).lower()`

Comment: Thank you. I have fixed all problems. :)